# How to avoid text-shadow overflowing other letters?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my view I have separate text-shadow styling for every single letter in a string.

But the text-shadow overflows on other letters.

[image: LIKE HERE]

How can I avoid this? Right now html for letters looks like that:

```
<p class="mainTxtWrapper">P</p>
<p class="mainTxtWrapper">r</p>
<p class="mainTxtWrapper">z</p>
<p class="mainTxtWrapper">e</p>
```

Shadow is dropped by jQuery function. Hiding overflow cuts badly the shadow.

My css for `<p>`

```
p {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

**NOTE:**
Shadows are dynamic generated and angle depends on cursor position, so it may move to the right.

Comment: I won't write this as an answer cause I'm not entirely sure it'll work, but you could wrap the paragraphs in a `div` and have this as `position: relative` then have each `<p>` tag as `position: absolute` with an increasing `z-index` so the first one would be `z-index: 0;` second `z-index: 1` and so on..

Comment: I would suggest not using the paragraph element for individual letters. Semantically, it's just wrong. Maybe a `span` element would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Baruch you can just set the `p` tags to `position: relative` and the `z-index` will apply. If you set them to `absolute` they'll all stack. Also, you want the first letter to be the highest `z-index` and decrement since the shadows are dropping to the left.

Comment: @wdm You're absolutely correct, thanks. (Note to self: Don't drink and StackOverflow)

Comment: I update my answer with a solution to shadow movement

Comment: Just curious, why separate letters?

Comment: @MarsAndBack because my text-shadow plugin was shading whole string, and for better effect I decided to split content for separate letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And idea is to play with the visual order using flexbox but you will have your text inverted in the code:

```css
.container {
  padding:5px 20px;
  background: pink;
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
  font-size:50px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#fff;
}
.mainTxtWrapper {
 text-shadow:-10px 0 10px blue;
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="mainTxtWrapper">e</p>
  <p class="mainTxtWrapper">z</p>
  <p class="mainTxtWrapper">r</p>
  <p class="mainTxtWrapper">p</p>
</div>

<div class="container" style="flex-direction:row;">
  <p class="mainTxtWrapper">e</p>
  <p class="mainTxtWrapper">z</p>
  <p class="mainTxtWrapper">r</p>
  <p class="mainTxtWrapper">p</p>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If the shadow can move from right to left, you can try something like this:

```css
.container {
  padding:5px 20px;
  background: pink;
  font-size:50px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:transparent;
  position:relative;
}
.container:before {
 content:attr(data-text);
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
 color:#fff;
}
.mainTxtWrapper {
 text-shadow:-10px 0 10px blue;
 margin:0;
 animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes change {
 to{text-shadow:10px 0 10px blue;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container" data-text="prze">
  <span class="mainTxtWrapper">p</span><span class="mainTxtWrapper">r</span><span class="mainTxtWrapper">z</span><span class="mainTxtWrapper">e</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Clever, i like it

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN! I had to use also `letter-spacing: -2px;` on `span`,  because shadow was shifted a bit in relation to the letters, but briliant approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every letter is wrapped in it's own `<p>`and the letters and their shadows therefore stack on top of each other.

#### Initial pragmatic approach

A possible solution (following @wdm's and @Baruch's comments) is to give every element that contains a letter a unique style and reorder them using [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). This also allows for different shadows per letter as in your example:

```css
.letter {
  position: relative;
  font-size:60px;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
}

.first {
  z-index: 4;
  text-shadow:  -12px 5px #33f;
}

.second {
  z-index: 3;
  text-shadow:  -5px 15px #33f;
}

.third {
  z-index: 2;
  text-shadow:  -25px -5px #33f;
}

.fourth {
  z-index: 1;
  text-shadow:  -25px 5px #33f;
}
```

```html
<span class="first letter">P</span>
<span class="second letter">r</span>
<span class="third letter">z</span>
<span class="fourth letter">e</span>
```

But as @Temani Afif pointed out correctly this is not really scalable and also as OP noted doesn't really solve the problem as it now overlaps text to the right.

#### The JavaScript approach

```js
const text = document.querySelector(".text");

const shadowContainer = document.createElement("div");
shadowContainer.classList.add("shadow-container");

text.appendChild(shadowContainer);

for(letter of text.textContent) {
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.textContent = letter;
  span.classList.add("shadow");
  shadowContainer.appendChild(span);
}
```

```css
.text {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.shadow-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.shadow {
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 4px #66f;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">Some long string of text<p>
```

This looks just like if we used regular `text-shadow`... But the trick is, that the shadow is actually generated by `span`s with the individual letter in them that are absolutely positioned behind the original text using `z-index: -1`. 
Now you can target the individual shadows without them overlapping the text. Thanks to JavaScript you also won't have to type that much in your HTML which makes it scalable.

Comment: and when we have 20 letters?

Comment: I was just about to add that this solution works but is not really scalable in the way presented! One alternative could be to set the z-index via JavaScript but I actually really like your idea of flexbox reordering as well!

Comment: Cool attempt, but the shadows for the letters are dynamic, depending on cursor position, and now letters on the right side are overflowed :/

Comment: Not sure if this is what you wanted to achieve @Przemyslaw.Pszemek but I had some fun with this concept and came up with this [codepen](https://codepen.io/luke-codewalker/pen/LBwXbb?editors=1000)

Comment: @luke-codewalker it is pretty nice, personally I just do not like shadows jumping around the letter. But I see, that I can deal with that modifying `shadow.style = 'left: ${xOffProp * 11}px; top: ${yOffProp * 10}px;';`